# If $f_i(X)$ is connected for all $i=1,2,...,n$ then $X$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology

For each $i\in\{1,...,n\}$, consider the map $f_i:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f_i(x)=x_i$ for all $x=(x_1,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$. I would like to know if the following statement is true or false: if $f_i(X)$ is connected for all $i=1,...,n$ then $X$ is connected.

Comment: It's false. Consider a set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is composed of a vertical ray emanating from the origin (sans the origin) and a horizontal ray emanating from the origin (sans the origin). What are the image sets for the $f_i$?

Comment: I don't think it's true. If I understand you correctly, you're describing the $i^{th}$ projection. Think of two sides of a square sharing a vertex; remove the vertex and you get a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Let $X$ be the graph of $y=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ together with the origin, a closed semicircle together with the centre of the circle. The projections are $[-1,1]$ on the $x$-axis and $[0,1]$ on the $y$-axis; these are both connected, but $X$ is not.

Comment: +$1$: Good and clear example!

Answer (score 1):

From my comment above:

It is definitely false. Consider a set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is composed of a vertical ray emanating from the origin (without the origin) and a horizontal ray emanating from the origin (also without the origin). This is a disconnected set. However the image sets for the $f_i$ are connected sets.

Answer (score 0):

The set $\{(x, y):  xy = 1, x > 0, y > 0\} \cup \{(0, 0)\}$  also provides a counter example.